# $A^k=B^k$ and $A,B$ are positive semidefinite $ \Rightarrow A = B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}$ and $A,B$ are positive semidefinite.

If there is $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $A^k=B^k$, why does $A=B$?

Comment: The conclusion of your question is not true. Take $k=2$ and $A=-B$ where $B$ is a matrix with zero eigenvalues.

Comment: @BeniBogosel, could you give a concrete example?

Comment: @Calle: Take $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @BeniBogosel, $A$ is not positive semidefinite. Compute $x^HAx$ for $x = \begin{pmatrix} -i & i \end{pmatrix}^T$ and you get $-1$. Compute it for $x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 + i & i \end{pmatrix}^T$ and you even get a non-real result.

Comment: @Calle: Ok, if you're working on complex spaces then things change.

Comment: Oh, actually, you don't need to use complex vectors. If you set $x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}^T$ you also get -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:
$A^k$ is diagonalizable since $A$ is. Thus $A^k=T\Lambda^k_a T^{-1}$ for some invertible $T$ if $A=T\Lambda_a T^{-1}$. $\Lambda_a$ is the diagonal matrix containing $A$'s eigenvalues. Now observe $B$ is diagonalizable as well and $A^k=B^k$ as per your assumption.

Comment: So $B^k=T\Lambda_a^k T^{-1}$, what next?

Comment: Thus if $B=T\Lambda_b T^{-1}$, then $\Lambda_b^k=\Lambda_a^k$ (try $det(A^k)=det(B^k)$). Now since they are diagonal and positive, since $A\geq 0$ and $B\geq 0$, $\Lambda_b=\Lambda_a$. Thus $A=B$.

Comment: I think the difficulty is why $B=T\Lambda_bT^{-1}$ not $B=P\Lambda_b P^{-1}$?

Comment: That follows because $B$ and $B^k$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. Conversely, any matrix that diagonalizes $B^k$ should also diagonalize $B$.

Comment: But you do not know a priori that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. So you could have $B = P \Lambda P$.

Comment: But I do know that $A^k$ and $B^k$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, since they are equal. Also $A^k$ is simultaneously diagonalizable with $A$ and so on.

Comment: Ok. Now I am also doubtful since positive definiteness doesn't imply diagonalizable unless it is symmetric.

Comment: But a positive definite operator on a Hilbert space is self-adjoint and hence symmetric.

Comment: A positive semidefinite matrix is not necessarily diagonalizable...

Comment: We are working in complex vector spaces here. What matters is if $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian (not symmetric). That $x^HAx \in \mathbb R$ for all $x$ is equivalent to $A$ being Hermitian, and this condition clearly holds in this case.

Answer (score 3):

So, okay, this will be an expansion on dineshdileep's answer, trying to puzzle all the pieces together. I will throughout assume we are working in complex spaces.

### Positive semi-definite implies Hermitian

Positive semi-definite means that $x^H A x \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb C^n$.

If $A$ is positive semi-definite, then $A$ is Hermitian. This is a special case of the following: If $x^HAx \in \mathbb R$ for all $x \in \mathbb C^n$, then $A$ is Hermitian.

*Proof*: From the assumption we have that
$$(x+y)^HA(x+y) = (x^HAx + y^HAy) + \underbrace{(x^HAy + y^HAx)}_{=B(x,y)}$$
is real. We know that $x^HAx + y^HAy$ is real by the assumption, so $B(x,y) = x^HAy + y^HAx$ must also be real. Now we get:
$$B(e_k, e_j) = a_{kj} + a_{jk} \in \mathbb R,$$
which implies $\operatorname{Im} a_{kj} = -\operatorname{Im} a_{jk}$. We also get:
$$B(ie_k,e_j) = -ia_{kj} +ia_{jk} \in \mathbb R,$$
which implies $\operatorname{Re} a_{kj} = \operatorname{Re} a_{jk}$.

These two facts together imply $a_{kj} = \overline{a_{jk}}$, which means that $A$ is Hermitian.

### Powers of positive semi-definite matrices are positive semi-definite

If $A$ is positive semi-definite, then so is $A^k$ for integers $k > 1$.

*Proof*: Positive semi-definite matrices can be characterized by the fact that all its eigenvalues are non-negative. Note that that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A^k$ with eigenvalue $\lambda^k$. Hence $A^k$ will be Hermitian matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda^k \geq 0$, since $\lambda \geq 0$, so $A^k$ is positive semi-definite.

### Uniqueness of $k$th roots for positive semi-definite matrices

Let $A$ be a positive semi-definite matrix. Then there exists a unique positive semi-definite matrix $B$ such that $B^k = A$.

*Proof*: Since $A$ is Hermitian, it can unitarily diagonalized, say $A = TDT^H$, where $D = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$. Since a solution $B$ to $B^k = A$ would commute with $A$, it can be simultaneously diagonalized with $A$, so $B = TD_BT^H$, for a diagonal matrix $D_B$. From the equation $B^k = A$ we get $D_B^k = D$, from which we get $D_B = \operatorname{diag}( \sqrt[k]{\lambda_1}, \dots, \sqrt[k]{\lambda_n})$ where the $k$th roots are unique.

Comment: Let $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_n$ be the diagonal elements in $D_B$. Then we actually solve the equations $\mu_i^k = \lambda_i$ when solving for $D_B$. These equations do of course have other solutions than the non-negative ones, but if we pick any of these, then $B$ would lose the property of being positive semi-definite and/or Hermitian (Hermitian matrices only have real eigenvalues).

### Final result

Let $A, B$ be positive semi-definite matrices. If $A^k = B^k$, then $A = B$.

*Proof*: Since $A, B$ are positive semi-definite, we know that $A^k, B^k$ are also positive semi-definite. We can thus just take the positive semi-definite square roots on both sides of $A^k = B^k$ to arrive at $A = B$.

Comment: Calle, in general if $A=TD_AT^H$ and $BA=AB$ then we can not garantee that $B=TD_BT^H$. The only thing that we can garantee is there exists another unitary $R$ such tht $A=RD'_AR^H$ and $B=RD'_BR^H$. In this particular case, if $B^k=A=TD_AT^H$ then $B=TD_BT^H$, because the eigenvectors of $B^k$ are also eigenvectors of $B$, since $B$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: @Daniel, okay, what is your point?

Answer (score 3):

Here, I am using some ideas of Calle and dineshdileep to solve your problem.

Lemma: If $A$ is a positive semidefinite Hermitian matrix and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^k$ then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Proof: If $0<b$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$ then $b=a^k$, for some eigenvalue $a$ of $A$. Thus, $A^k-bId=A^k-a^kId=(A^{k-1}+aA^{k-2}+\ldots+a^{k-2}A+a^{k-1}Id)(A-aId)$. Since $a>0$ and $A$ is positive semidefinite then $(A^{k-1}+aA^{k-2}+\ldots+a^{k-2}A+a^{k-1}Id)$ is positive definite. Therefore the $\ker(A^{k}-bId)=\ker(A-aId)$.

Since $\text{rank}(A^k)=\text{rank}(A)=$ number of non-null eigenvalues of $A$ then $\dim(\ker(A))=\dim(\ker(A^k))$. Since $\ker(A)\subset\ker(A^k)$ then $\ker(A)=\ker(A^k)\ \ \ \square$.

Finally, if $A^k=B^k$ and $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite Hermitian matrices then, by the previous lemma, the eigenvectors of $A^k=B^k$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$. Thus, we can write $A=TD_AT^{-1}$ and $B=TD_BT^{-1}$, where $D_A$ and $D_B$ are positive semidefinite diagonal matrices. So $TD_A^kT^{-1}=TD_B^kT^{-1}$, which implies $D_A^k=D_B^k$. Since $D_A$ and $D_B$ are positive semidefinite diagonal matrices then $D_A=D_B$.